# JavaScript mouseenter event not working when mouse is down

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I have an `<input type="range">` scroll and a `div` that on `mouseover` and `mouseleave` changes its background. You can see the working code here: http://jsfiddle.net/y8S57/ , please use a Webkit browser as `type="range"` works only on Webkit.

The problem is that if the mouse is down on the `type="range"` button and enters the `mouseover` and `mouseleave` zone the respective events are not triggered. Somehow using the `type="range"` cancels the other events that should be happening.

How can I fix this so when I drag the `<input type="range">` and my mouse is over that `mouseover` `div` the `mouseover` event to trigger?

HTML:

```
<input id="zoom" type="range" name="zoom" min="10" max="100" step="1" value="40" >
<div id="zone"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#zone").mouseenter(function(){
   $(this).css({background:"red"});
});

$("#zone").mouseleave(function(){
   $(this).css({background:"black"});
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately it looks like WebKit just isn't firing mouse events on other elements here.  All I can offer you is how to shorten your code down:

```
$("#zone").hover(function(){
   $(this).css({background:"red"});
}, function(){
   $(this).css({background:"black"});
});
```

This isn't a bug you can fix (and may certainly be *intentional* behavior by the browser), posting it on the [WebKit Bugzilla](https://bugs.webkit.org/) will do the most good here.  By intentional I mean they probably actively do this for other reasons, for example when you go crazy dragging you wouldn't want to trigger a flyout menu that covers the slider all the sudden.

Comment: Thanx Nick. I think that this is intentionaland not a bug but I was looking for a way to bypass this. It looks like mousedown is canceling all the other events out there and there is nothing I can do about that.

Comment: @Mircea - I have to agree, not much you can do here...and like the example I gave above I do understand why they'd choose to do this...I don't think the behavior's going anywhere.

Comment: I understand. I will mark this answer as accepted as there is no solution to this at this time. Thanx

Comment: Thanks nick it's working great for div. This is great alternative for           $("#divMain").mouseove(function () {
              $(this).css("overflow", "auto");
              isRefresh = "false";
          }).mouseout(function () {
              $(this).css("overflow", "hidden").scrollTop(1);
              isRefresh = "true";
          });